# Find the difference between data in 2 columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 sets of data. I put it in Excel e.g. column A and column B. Now I want to know which data from B is part of column A. I run this formula =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$327238,B1)>0,"Exist", "Nope")
Then I 'filter it and look only 'Exist'. Based on that I know that all data in B that has label 'Exist' is part of column A
Now I want to know opposite i.e. which data from A are part of B. For that reason I use the same formula but I replace the data in columns i.e. data from B now in A and vice versa.
Then I randomly verify results.
For case 1 it looks it works fine but for second case it looks it's not accurate.
My assumption: should it work in case 2 as well ( maybe I just was not very accurate in some way ) and I should expect it to work?
Thanks

Comment: Yes - you should expect it to work (and it should work, unless you made a mistake)

Comment: What sort of data is in the two columns?

Comment: Column A:B are not populated to the same extent. The data in cell is a mixture of text and number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In cell `C1` (assuming your data starts from 1st row) type the following `=IF(A2=B2,"equal","no")`, and then populate the same formula to the last row where there is still data, so that for row `N`, your formula in column `C` is `=IF(AN=BN,"equal","no")`. After that you will just need to count the cells with value "no" to know the differences. Sorry if I didn't get the question correctly.

Ok, assuming that the two sets of data are in columns A and B (they might be of different sizes), and the last rows of data are L and M respectively, click on D1 and type the following: `=IFNA(INDEX(B$1:B$5,MATCH(A1,B$1:B$5,0),1),"Unique")`. Drag down to apply this formula on D1 - DL. That's it, you have the duplicate elements. Since the duplicate elements are the same in both columns - A and B, you don't need to repeat this for column B. Note, that for all the unique elements the corresponding rows of column D have the word "Unique", so if you want the unique elements, you can just get the elements from A with the mentioned row numbers:

Just select any column's first row cell and type the following formula: `=IF(D1="Unique",INDEX(A$1:A$L,ROW(D1)),"Duplicate")`.

Comment: OP is trying to find out the intersect between two lists of values: they are not matching row-by-row

Comment: Right. Data on a2 and b2 might be not equal and that is not my goal. My goal is to find that somewhere in column A there is data equal to b2. This should be true on those rows next to "Exist". Based on Tim Williams response I will assume that it should work in both cases